# Python Regular Expression email

Tags: python, regex, email, expression

let´s say I have an array of email adresses and with RE pattern I need to print only those which have ´uniba.sk´ in them.

```
import re
p = ['my.name@euniba.sk', 'your.name@uniba.sk', 'people@dkd.ffff.uniba.sk']
def function(p):
    for i in p:
        if re.match(r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w*(uniba\.sk)+)\"?", i):
            print(i)
```

But this only gives me first or second type of mail from array. BUT the first type of email with euniba.sk is incorect so that should not be printed.

I am new in RE so I would need help, what I am doing wrong? Or how can I create the correct pattern for this?

Comment: If you need to match `uniba\.sk` as a whole word, just use `\buniba\.sk\b`

Comment: \"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@w*(uniba\.sk)+)

Comment: @GauravOjha thanks, this helped me to get rid of euniba, but what if I have some words before uniba.sk something like dkd.ffff.uniba.sk?